# How to assign plugin to top level menu?

Tags: plugins, menus

wp-content/plugins/myplugin.php

how to assign this plugin to top level menu? E.g. menu on my website: about us contacts, services my plugin. I'm using add_menu_page but I dont know why its not working.

Comment: Why do you need to show that in a Menu. Plugins are mostly back end features. Why do you need them in a front-end menu? [Edit] your question and add more details, and add proper context.

Comment: I need to make custom module for wordpress. How do this the best way?

Comment: [Writing a plugin - the WordPress' way](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) - for your newly created plugin, find that in `example.com/wp-admin/plugins.php`, you will get your plugin listed there. Activate it and do your tweaks.

Comment: it's already activated. but I dont know how to make it on the tol level menu.

Comment: `add_menu_page()` is the key. [Edit] your question and share your code please. Please don't fill comment area with branches of the question.

Answer (score 0):

apply `$position` you want in your `add_menu_page` please refer here for more details

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page